# Drools DRL: Fewer larger rules vs many smaller rules

Tags: drools

I have many rule constraints that can be logically grouped together by "or". For example: 3 rules "r1", "r2" and "r3". I can construct a single LHS as:

```
(r1 || r2 || r3)
```

Or I can make each of them a separate rule. I have no critical functional requirement for doing it either way since I can detect their grouping independently outside of Drools.

I wonder if one way is more advantageous than the other from runtime execution perspective (performance, memory, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A disjunction at *pattern level* is handled very much like two different rules, so there's not much gained or lost either way.

But from a maintenance and development point of view, two separate rules require two copies of the right hand side, so using a disjunction in a single rule appears to be preferable.

Establishing binding variables used to be a little tricky but I think that recent versions (6.x) of Drools handle that satisfactorily.

Note that disjunctions at *constraint* level should definitely not be split into separate rules.

Comment: That is the answer (confirmation) I needed. Thank you. Just to clarify a little bit (in case I missed something): I AM splitting the constraints. My use case is a very simple one. The  constraints are effectively "filters" on the fact objects. If the fact matches any constraint, I collect the matched fact. Since all filters are in a disjunction, I think I can safely split them. Multiple matching of the same fact is fine since I only care to know which facts matched. Does it make sense? Or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: So if you are looking for `kind == "apple"` or `kind == "banana"`, and so on, with each of these constraints in a different rule you are creating overhead needlessly. (Of course, catching the fruits in a Set will weed out duplicates.) Also, you might miss simpler ways of writing these filters, e.g., by using `kind in ("apple", "banana", "cherry")`.